# How can I send multi-dimensional arrays with Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable

Should I use Parcelable? Because that does not seem to accept multi-dimensional arrays like for example int[][]

(I need to send data between activities)

Comment: Could you provide some more context? Otherwise you might get really few (useful) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are covariant in Java (and they all extend Object).
Therefore, you can assign an array of arrays (like `int[][]`) to an `Object[]` array, simply because an array is an object: `int[][]` means an array of `int[]` and `int[]` is an `Object`.

With generics, if you have a type `T` and an array `T[]`, defining `T` as `int[]` would result in that array being exactly `int[][]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't really get it. Could you provide a sample that shows how you transfer a multidimensional array from one activity to another? Could I even use a Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite late to the game, but this is the solution I used:

```
private void write2DimArray(int[][] array, Parcel parcel) {
    parcel.writeInt(array.length);
    for(int[] arrayDim1 : array) {
        parcel.writeInt(arrayDim1.length);
        parcel.writeIntArray(arrayDim1);
    }
}

private int[][] read2DimArray(Parcel parcel) {
    int[][] array = new int[parcel.readInt()][];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int arraySize = parcel.readInt();
        array[i] = new int[arraySize];
        parcel.readIntArray(array[i]);
    }
    return array;
}
```